# How to make an android application autostart only when the battery gets to a 20 % level? battery saving application

Tags: android

I would like to make a battery saving application that will auto start when the battery level gets to 20 percent, meaning it should always be active once
installed. I have no I dea how to keep the application listening as well as how to make the application auto start when it gets its desired battery
percentage which is 20 percent at which it must autostart

Comment: If you are willing to simply accept when the battery gets "low", register a `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest for `ACTION_BATTERY_LOW`.

Comment: I need to get the battery level as an integer in real-time in other words so I can perhaps give a notification at 30% and autostart at 20%. I hope you can help. Thanks a million times in advance

Answer (score 1):

20% is too rigid a scale. As @CommonsWare suggests, an easier, more ideal approach would be for a broadcastReceiver to start your application on ACTION_BATTERY_LOW intent. Keep in mind that that could mean 15%, or even 10% depending on the device make and model.

On a side note, how is this battery saving if you are starting it after your battery level is already low?Perhaps you mean , you want to kill/stop your app when the device battery is low ?

Comment: So there is no possibility whatsoever of getting it to launch at 20% or receiving the battery status as an integer in real time? And it is battery saving in the sense that when the application starts it saves on the remaining battery time, which is why I wanted it to auto start at 20% and not the automated system percentage. Please help